# New line in alert window with jQuery jqXHR responseText

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string, alert

I'm currently requesting some text via jQuery on a php page. The problem is that the new line symbols `\n` are displayed in the alert window, and do not get interpreted as new line. I do not escape the string at any time.
In the `error: function(..)` block of my jQuery request, I get the string returned by php via `jqXHR.responseText`, here is it's exact value :

```
Some fields are empty!\n$name= \n$schedule= 480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140\n$free_connection= false\n$free_coffee= false\n$rating= -1\n$lat= 44.715513732021336\n$lng= 1.9775390625\n
```

When I do this, new lines **DON'T WORK** :

```
alert(jqXHR.responseText);
```

So to debug, I decided to paste the php response string (which is the previous string) directly in the `alert()` function, and in this case the new lines **WORK**   :

```
 alert("Some fields are empty!\n$name= \n$schedule= 480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140\n$free_connection= false\n$free_coffee= false\n$rating= -1\n$lat= 44.715513732021336\n$lng= 1.9775390625\n)");
```

The string is exactly the same, but yet new lines don't work when I use jqXHR to get it.
Anybody has any clue ?

**EDIT:** php code that generates the string :

```
$errorMessage = 'Some fields are empty!' . '\n'
              . '$name= '               . $name . '\n'
              . '$schedule= '           . $schedule . '\n'
              . '$free_connection= '    . $free_connection . '\n'
              . '$free_coffee= '        . $free_coffee . '\n'
              . '$rating= '             . $rating . '\n'
              . '$lat= '                . $lat . '\n'
              . '$lng= '                . $lng . '\n';
echo $errorMessage;
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText))` to see what that actually looks like?

Comment: I just tried, the value is exactly the one I quoted : `Some fields are empty!\n$name= \n$schedule= 480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140;480;1140\n$free_connection= false\n$free_coffee= false\n$rating= -1\n$lat= 44.902577996288876\n$lng= 3.4716796875\n`

Comment: @VickyGonsalves I can't my php server sending the response to the jQuery request is on localhost

Comment: It sounds like the response has literal `\n` in it, not newline characters. Can you show the PHP code you use to create the response

Comment: @Barmar Well you're right! I used '\n' instead of "\n" (double quote). Now it works
You can write an answer to my SO question and I'll accept it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong type of quotes. In PHP, escape sequences aren't processed in single quotes, only in double quotes. So it should be:

```
$errorMessage = 'Some fields are empty!' . "\n"
              . '$name= '               . $name . "\n"
              . '$schedule= '           . $schedule . "\n"
              . '$free_connection= '    . $free_connection . "\n"
              . '$free_coffee= '        . $free_coffee . "\n"
              . '$rating= '             . $rating . "\n"
              . '$lat= '                . $lat . "\n"
              . '$lng= '                . $lng . "\n";
echo $errorMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood well but You can try

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

or

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```